# delete item that are not present on another database

Tags: php, mysql

I tried this code to delete the item that not present on another database what should i do ?

```
mysqli_query($link,"delete from payment where INVOICE_NO_MX NOT IN(select * from invoice) ");
```

Comment: You can't do `select *` inside in the `IN()` function, just select the column name which is same as `INVOICE_NO_MX`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be comparing `INVOICE_NO_MX` against the correct *column* in `invoice`.  Something like this:

```
DELETE
FROM payment
WHERE INVOICE_NO_MX NOT IN (SELECT INVOICE_NO_MX FROM invoice)
                                    ^^^ replace with appropriate column name
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace * with appropriate field name.

```
select '*' from invoice.
```

This query returns multiple columns but in sub-query you can return only 1 column or summary functions.

Hope this will solve your problem.